# datetime field is not allowing to search with use of date only by MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

My MySQL table has `START_DATE(datetime)`. The value stores in this field like `2014-02-05 12:50:16`.

Now I have tried `SELECT * FROM table WHERE START_DATE= '2014-02-05'`. 
It returns empty value. So, Please help me to `SELECT` values by date.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Date` function on the datetime field to compare.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Date(START_DATE)= '2014-02-05'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed column name in your query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE START_DATE like '2014-02-05%'
```

it will match date and it will return all data with 2014-02-05 date.

Comment: sorry, Mistake in my question. .now i have corrected it

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE START_DATE like '2014-02-05%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE CAST(START_DATE AS DATE) = '20140205'
```

**OR**

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE CAST(START_DATE AS DATE) = '2014-02-05'
```

The 1st query is SARGable. it allows your query engine to use indexes on your START_DATE column.